# Magento 2 Is it OK to create a database table directly via MySQL Management tool?

Tags: magento2, database

Is it **OK** to create a new database table directly via MySQL Managentment tool instead of using intallData.php for Magento 2? I know it's technically possible, but is it OK to do it this way, and it won't break anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what the goal of it is, e.g is it a `temp table` to store temporary stuff .. etc. Using the magento's setup upgrade is always good because you can port it to environments and its one less manually thing to do, unless you make it part of your deployment process e.g Jenkins.

Also there is a chance you will forget you create that table in a few months time.